# How to receive messages from backend asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jakarta-ee

I need to verify usernames, so when user enters the username it should be sent to backend to verify its availability. I have the following code but have doubt in receiving the available or unavailable message from backend.

```
   function verifyUsername(value){
           if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                  document.getElementById("mymessage").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                } 
            }
            xmlhttp.open("get","verifyUsername?username="+value,false);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }


  ....
  <div id="mymessage"></div>
   ....
```

**Server End Psuedo Code (actual implementation: Java)**

```
 ....
 if(verify(username))
    return "Username is not available";
 else
   return "username is available";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a jQuery example of this, I won't bother with the pure JavaScript version. What you are looking for is a callback function to fire once the ajax request has been returned.

```
// listen to a click event on a button OR something 
$("#buttonName").on("click", function(event){

    // prevent any default activity
    event.preventDefault();

    // get your value 
    var value = $("#mymessage").val();

    // jQuery ajax event
    $.ajax({
      url : "verifyUsername?username="+value,
      type: 'GET'
    }).done(function ( data ) {
       if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "Data returned :"+data )
       // do something else
    }
    }):
```

.done() is the success callback option, there are others as well:

```
    // jQuery ajax event
        $.ajax({
          url : "verifyUsername?username="+value,
          type: 'GET'
        })
    // successful callback
    .done(function(){ // success })
    // fail/error callback
    .fail(function(){ // fail })
    // completed callback 
    .always(function(){ // will always execute, even if request fails })
});
```

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thanks but how to associate it to onclick ? so once user type the data and clicks on textbox triggers this function?

Comment: There are a few approaches to this. You listen for an event, click, keydown etc. I'll update my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the problem correctly, it is, "returning the correct response back from the server-side". 
The actual implementation is mentioned as Java, so I am assuming there is a backend Servlet that the Ajax request submits to. 
You would need to get a handle on the HttpServletResponse object in your doGet method(as you are using get), add your logic to verify the username and the send the response text back.
Something like

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    String username = request.getParameter(username);
    String responseText = "";
    boolean isUserAval;
    //add your logic to verify username setting isUserAval to true/false accordingly

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    if(isUserAval)
    {
       responseText = "Username is available";
    }
    else
    {
       responseText = "Username is not available";
    }
    out.println(responseText);
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function below... You'll also notice, request will have a readystate and stuff like that, your looking for prolly statusCode between 200-202, and ready state of 4, and a statusText of OK

```
var request = $.get(url, function(event){
   //If your within your application your url can be the method you need
   //I.E. Ruby URL post would be /api/v1/users/find_user_by_ID
   //This URL Points to the api/v1 folder than the users controller
   //Than finally the method inside the controller (find_user_by_ID)
}
```

I also believe that whatever your doing, doesn't need to be in javascript, if your using PHP or Ruby, you can simply add php or ruby tags and create if statements, than use javascript to add and remove classes, or toggle hide and show dependent on what happened in each step.